# io.to('socketId') not emitting the event

Tags: node.js, angular, io, socket.io

I want to send message to specific socket . I have saved the socketId in mongoo db . when i emit the event its not emitting the event . its works fine if i emit without specific socket what could be the issue ./ please help me 
here is my code

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('save-message-private',function(data){
console.log('private messgae ')
OnlineUsers.find({username:data.receiver},function(err,res){
  if(!err){
  //  console.log(res)
    console.log(res[0].socketId)
    io.to(res[0].socketId).emit('new-message-private', { message: res });
  }
  else
  console.log(err)

  })
 })
  });
```

And here is my front end in angular 4

```
ngOnInit() {

var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
console.log(user)
if(user!==null) {
  this.socket=io('http://localhost:4000',{query:"username="+user.nickname});
  this.getChatByRoom(user.room);
  this.msgData = { room: user.room, nickname: user.nickname, message: '',receiver:'group'  }
  this.joinned = true;
  this.scrollToBottom();
  this.getOnlineUsers();
  this.socket.on('new-message', function (data) {
    if(data.message.room === JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).room) {
      this.chats.push(data.message);
      this.msgData = { room: user.room, nickname: user.nickname, message: '' }
      this.scrollToBottom();
    }
  }.bind(this));

  this.socket.on('new-message-private',function(data){
    console.log('private new')
    console.log(data);
  }.bind(this));
}

}
```

new-private-message not working

Comment: Can you `console.log(this.socket.id)` on the client site where you expect to recive the message and check if it is the same id as you are logging at the server `console.log(res[0].socketId)`?

Comment: on server side it consoling the socketId but its not emitting event on that socket @RolandStarke

Comment: it giving my undefined on client side @RolandStarke

Comment: log it after you are connected.

Comment: it is different from server side

Comment: Mh you should figure out why :D

Comment: I have closed the work now will work tomorrow . I am stuck there :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My socketId saved in db was different from client side socketId . so I updated the socketId on db and problem solved